# reduceByKey method not being found in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

Here is code I'm trying out for reduceByKey :

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import scala.math.random

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel

object MapReduce {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

  val sc = new SparkContext("local[4]" , "")

  val file = sc.textFile("c:/data-files/myfile.txt")

  val counts = file.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
    .map(word => (word, 1))
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)

  }

}
```

Is giving compiler error : "cannot resolve symbol reduceByKey"

When I hover over implementation of reduceByKey it gives three possible implementations so it appears it is being found ?:

[image]

Comment: Does is compile with SBT?

Comment: I wouldn't trust IntelliJ Idea type inference and thus suggestions that much. It happened a lot of time to me to see errors in IntelliJ that weren't real errors. Probably you are seeing a suggestion that isn't really available.

Comment: @Aldo Stracquadanio yep this was my issue, seems like it compiles but still displays errors.

Comment: @maasg im not using SBT for compilation, just Intellij & Maven

Comment: What is maven saying? I tried on the REPL and it works fine. It's probably only an IntelliJ hiccups.

Comment: @maasg yes works fine on REPL for me also. Maven is not displaying an error, just IntelliJ

Comment: I recommend using SBT in conjunction with Intellij. It has a nice tool; "gen-idea" that generates an Intellij project for you and works all nicely with any external packages.

Answer (score 11):

You need to add the following import to your file:

***import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._***

**Spark documentation:**

"*In Scala, these operations are automatically available on RDDs containing Tuple2 objects (the built-in 
tuples in the language, created by simply writing (a, b)), **as long as you import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._** in your program to enable Spark’s implicit conversions. The key-value pair operations are available in the PairRDDFunctions class, which automatically wraps around an RDD of tuples if you import the conversions.*"

Comment: As per my answer below, this has changed in Spark 1.4.x.  While the import has been dropped from the documentation, it is still required for IntelliJ to work and is now different:

    import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD._

Answer (score 3):

It seems as if the documented behavior has changed in Spark 1.4.x.  To have IntelliJ recognize the implicit conversions you now have to add the following import:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD._
```

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed that at times IJ is unable to resolve methods that are **imported implicitly via PairRDDFunctions**  https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala .

The methods implicitly imported include the **reduceByKey*** and **reduceByKeyAndWindow*** methods.  I do not have a general solution at this time -except that yes you can safely ignore the intellisense errors